# How to find string that matches at least 2 keywords php

Tags: php, arrays, regex, search, strpos

It could be stupid question but is there any decent and efficient way to provide search on string without writing down a tons of code?

The trouble is that I need to **match at least 2 keywords** inside string before future code processing.

I did try regex,preg_match,strpos and now trying with arrays but getting nowhere.

Here is a bit of code I'm working on right now:

```
$keywords = array('lorem','ipsum','dog','cat' );
            $text="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur";

            if (count(array_intersect(explode(' ', $text),$keywords))) {
              echo '<p>'.$message_id_that_contains_at_least_2_keywords.'</p><br>';
              }
```

It doesn't has to be array method, could be anything that do not kill my server :)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just build a regex with OR '|' for all the keyword, match them and Count the matches. It should be >= 2.

Comment: Thank You  @PoulBak , it make sense, will try it right now.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/54fd65903e12c275bae6c89684fc15b52ab8b10c

Comment: @splash58 You are a STAR!!! That is exactly what I was looking for. Just brilliant :) Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
$keywords = array('lorem','ipsum','dog','cat' );
$text="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur";

preg_match_all('/\b('.implode('|', array_map('preg_quote',$keywords)).')\b/i',  $text, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => lorem
            [1] => ipsum
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => lorem
            [1] => ipsum
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db803510203d2977de7e39d8235d7725cfdc90f6)

- `\b` is the word boundary (things like spaces, punctuation)
- `( ... )` is a capture group
- `|` is or

So the Regex looks like `/\b(lorem|ipsum|dog|cat)\b/i`.  And then `preg_quote` escapes things that are important in Regex in the keywords (just in case).  Things like `.` which is any character need to be escaped.

If you want to make sure you have `x` number of matches, then you just count.

```
 if(isset($matches[1]) && count($matches[1]) > 2) then do something....
```

In this case you could use the `0` index, but it's more proper to use `1` because that is for the first capture group, where 0 is for any matches.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it sorted :)

Comment: Sure it also works good for hi-lighting, for example `str_replace($matches[1][0], '<span class="hilight">'.$matches[1][0].'</span>', $text);`